# Alpaca Form Wizard - Send Form by POST Method

Tags: ajax, ajaxform, alpacajs

I'm new in Alpaca Forms and on Stack Overflow.

I'm trying to send a form by using a Wizard.
I tried a lot of solutions, but I'm in doubt about the way to do it.

I have changed the insertion of "attributes", "form" and "buttons" but nothing is working.

Does somebody have an idea about what is wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#form1").alpaca({
"dataSource": "./data/customer-profile-data.json",
"schemaSource": "./data/customer-profile-schema.json",
"optionsSource": "./data/customer-profile-options.json",
"view": {
    "parent": "bootstrap-edit-horizontal",
    "wizard": {
        "title": "Welcome to the Wizard",
        "description": "Please fill things in as you wish",
        "bindings": {
            "name": 1,
            "age": 1,
            "gender": 1,
            "photo": 1,
            "member": 2,
            "phone": 2,
            "icecream": 3,
            "address": 3,
        },
        "steps": [{
            "title": "Getting Started",
            "description": "Basic Information"
        }, {
            "title": "Details",
            "description": "Personal Information"
        }, {
            "title": "Preferences",
            "description": "Customize your Profile",
        }],
        "form" : {
             "method" : "POST",
             "action" : "http://httpbin.org/post",
           },
           "buttons" : {
               "submit" : {
                   "title" : "Sauve Response",
                   "id": "mySubmit",
                   "click": function(callback){
                     console.log("submit() - ".$("#form1"));
                   },
               }
             },
        /*"attributes": {
            "data-test": "123",
            "method": "post",
            "action": "http://httpbin.org/post"
        },
        "buttons": {
          "submit":{
            "value": "Sumbit",
          }
        }
        //"validation": true,
      /*  "buttons": {
            /*"first": {
                "title": "Go to First Page",
                "align": "left",
                "click": function(e) {
                    this.trigger("moveToStep", {
                        "index": 0,
                        "skipValidation": true
                    });
                }
            },
            "previous": {
                "validate": function(callback) {
                    console.log("Previous validate()");
                    callback(true);
                }
            },
            "next": {
                "validate": function(callback) {
                    console.log("Next validate()");
                    callback(true);
                }
            },*/
    /*        "submit": {
                "title": "All Done!",
                "name": "submit",
                "type": "submit",
                "id": "mySubmit",
                "click": function(callback){
                  console.log("submit()");
                },
                "submit": function(callback){
                  console.log("Next validate()");
                }
            }
        }*/
    },
    //"locale": "es_ES
    "locale": "fr_FR",
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

To do this you can use ajax or jquery post method in the click event on your submit button like this :

```
$.post( "//httpbin.org/post", this.getValue());
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/wco1e57n/) for this.